# Invalid constructor error in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile a C++ code and below is the code snippet, I have added the error below this code snippet.

```
// Move constructor
    CLM(const CLM&& other)
    {
        this->detection_success = other.detection_success;
        this->tracking_initialised = other.tracking_initialised;
        this->detection_certainty = other.detection_certainty;
        this->model_likelihood = other.model_likelihood;
        this->failures_in_a_row = other.failures_in_a_row;

        pdm = other.pdm;
        params_local = other.params_local;
        params_global = other.params_global;
        detected_landmarks = other.detected_landmarks;
        landmark_likelihoods = other.landmark_likelihoods;
        patch_experts = other.patch_experts;
        landmark_validator = other.landmark_validator;


        triangulations = other.triangulations;
        kde_resp_precalc = other.kde_resp_precalc;
    }

    // Assignment operator for rvalues
    CLM & operator= (const CLM&& other)
    {
        this->detection_success = other.detection_success;
        this->tracking_initialised = other.tracking_initialised;
        this->detection_certainty = other.detection_certainty;
        this->model_likelihood = other.model_likelihood;
        this->failures_in_a_row = other.failures_in_a_row;

        pdm = other.pdm;
        params_local = other.params_local;
        params_global = other.params_global;
        detected_landmarks = other.detected_landmarks;
        landmark_likelihoods = other.landmark_likelihoods;
        patch_experts = other.patch_experts;
        landmark_validator = other.landmark_validator;


        triangulations = other.triangulations;
        kde_resp_precalc = other.kde_resp_precalc;
        return *this;
    }
```

I get the below error:

```
In file included from ../../Demo/Pack/CLM/include/CLM_utils.h:9:0,
                 from ../../Demo/Pack/CLM/src/CCNF_patch_expert.cpp:3:
../../Demo/Pack/CLM/include/CLM.h:170:16: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&&’ token
   CLM(const CLM&& other)
                ^
../../Demo/Pack/CLM/include/CLM.h:170:24: error: invalid constructor; you probably meant ‘CLMTracker::CLM (const CLMTracker::CLM&)’
   CLM(const CLM&& other)
                        ^
../../Demo/Pack/CLM/include/CLM.h:192:28: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&&’ token
  CLM & operator= (const CLM&& other)
                            ^
../../Demo/Pack/CLM/include/CLM.h: In member function ‘CLMTracker::CLM& CLMTracker::CLM::operator=(CLMTracker::CLM)’:
../../Demo/Pack/CLM/include/CLM.h:194:29: error: ‘other’ was not declared in this scope
   this->detection_success = other.detection_success;
```

I dont know what is wrong with the code and what the error meant? Can some one please help.

Comment: Seems like your compiler doesn't support C++11.

Comment: 1) did you compile with C++11 support enabled? 2) const rvalue references are rather pointless.

Comment: Unrelated: The traditional TLA of CLM made me smile, I must admit.

Comment: If your "move constructor" is just going to do a copy, you may as well omit it and let the copy constructor be selected

Comment: and if your copy semantics is to copy each member then omit both and use the default-generated versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const CLM&& other` is an *r-value reference*. These are new additions to C++ from the C++11 standard. Add `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x` if you are using an older compiler, check the documentation) to your compiler invocation.

Comment: Accepted as answer, as it is answered first. @Ivaylo Strandjev Thanks for your answer too and your reference link.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `&&` which is an [rvalue reference](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2118.html) and it only has meaning in `c++11`. Thus you should tell your compiler you are using `c++11`. In GCC you do that by passing `-std=c++11`